# Is there a window manager that allows you to set environment variables

Tags: linux, environment-variables

My problem here is that I often stays logged in for a considerable amount of time and the usual methods of setting environment variables doesn't work in a satisfactory way:

If I set environment variables in a shell only processes started from that particular shell is being affected. On the other hand if I try to put the environment variables in the login script (.profile, .xinitrc or whatever) I will need to log out and log in in order for the changes to take effect.

The ideal solution is to have the functionality in the window manager since it's the process that ultimately starts all other processes on behalf of the user (correct me if I'm wrong or terribly wrong). (The corresponding solution if using terminal login would be to set the environment variable in the login shell.)

Is there a window manager (or similar) that solves this problem?

Comment: Are you asking how to set an environment variable and NOT having to log out and log back in to your X session (via the window manager) to have the variable take effect? Otherwise `the usual methods of setting environment variables` will accomplish what you want (save having to log out/in)

Comment: Yes, exactly - I want to avoid having to log out/in. I realize of course that changes won't have effect on already started processes (except the windowmanager), but that's fine for me.